# Build once and deploy for many environments

Tags: java, maven, deployment, web-deployment

We have legacy system with 50 -60 maven modules, all of these modeules have used maven resource plugin to filter properties (replace tokens at build time in property files).  This is very painful when it comes to build for different environments, because we have to build the application each time when we need to deploy for different environments.

We have a new requirement to build the application once and deploy for many environments. What would be the best solution for this? I was think of externalizing the filter properties, but biggest issue is to replace the token of the existing property files of the application (see application.properties) file below. I want to keep the existing property files as it is and pick the values from external config file.

Any help would be much appreciate it.

e.g
**Filter.properties injected to maven.**

```
generic.sharepoint.host=xxxxx
generic.deploy.apps.host=xxxxx
generic.deploy.apps.url=xxxx
generic.deploy.trusted.host=xxxx
generic.deploy.trusted.url=xxxx
generic.deploy.orderentry=xxxxx
```

**application.properties**

```
generic.sharepoint.host=${generic.sharepoint.host}
generic.deploy.apps.host=${generic.deploy.apps.host}
generic.deploy.apps.url=${generic.deploy.apps.url}
generic.deploy.trusted.host=${generic.deploy.trusted.host}
generic.deploy.trusted.url=${generic.deploy.trusted.url}
generic.deploy.orderentry=${generic.deploy.orderentry}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my experience I also had to build a Spring based web application once and deploy on many different environments, so I'm trying to show you the solution that worked fine for me.

I couldn't find a way to hand off this task to Maven, so I decided to externalize configuration and found that exploiting Spring I could manage to achieve that only performing two steps:

1. Make the application 'aware' of the environment it was deployed to, by reading a file containing the environment's name (e.g. DEV, TEST, PRODUCTION)
2. Accordingly to the environment value found,set a system property and then load the config file placed in the correspondent folder.

Having Tomcat, we set the configuration folder structure under `shared/classes` in a way like this:

[image: config structure]

and we put in the `application-config folder` the `application-config.properties` file containing the descripton of the environment:

```
application-config.env=DEV
```

and the same configuration files under every single child folder properly configured as the related environment required. 
After that we had to add to the Spring application context another `application-config-context.xml` with some bean definitions in order to interact with the `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

  <bean id="environmentDetector" class="com.mycompany.myapp.spring.util.PropertiesBasedEnvironmentDetector" init-method="init" >
    <property name="properties" ref="environmentDefinitionProperties" />
    <property name="environmentDefinitionPropertyName" value="application-config.env"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="environmentDefinitionProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
      <list>
        <value>classpath:application-config/application-config.properties</value>
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" >
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="false" />
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="properties" ref="applicationExternalProperties" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="applicationExternalProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean" >
    <property name="location" value="${application-config.prefix}application-config/${application-config.env}/application.properties" />
  </bean>

</beans>
```

I had to code a class to override the Spring's `postProcessBeanFactory` method of the interface  `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanFactoryPostProcessor` like this:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp.doc.spring.util;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanFactoryPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.PriorityOrdered;

public class PropertiesBasedEnvironmentDetector implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor, PriorityOrdered{
    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(PropertiesBasedEnvironmentDetector.class);

    private Properties properties;
    private String environmentDefinitionPropertyName ="env";
    private String defaultEnvironment="DEV";
    private String environmentSystemPropertyName;
    private int order = PriorityOrdered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;

    private String prefixSystemPropertyName = "application-config.prefix";
    private String prefixDefault = "classpath:";
    private String prefix;

    public void setProperties(Properties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        if (environmentSystemPropertyName == null) {
            environmentSystemPropertyName = environmentDefinitionPropertyName;
        }
        String activeEnvironment = properties.getProperty(environmentDefinitionPropertyName, defaultEnvironment);
        prefix = properties.getProperty(prefixSystemPropertyName);
        if (prefix == null) {
            prefix = prefixDefault;
            properties.put(prefixSystemPropertyName, prefix);
        }
        System.setProperty(environmentSystemPropertyName , activeEnvironment);
        System.setProperty(prefixSystemPropertyName , prefix);

        log.warn("Initializing Environment: "+activeEnvironment);

    }

    public String getEnvironmentDefinitionPropertyName() {
        return environmentDefinitionPropertyName;
    }

    public void setEnvironmentDefinitionPropertyName(
        String environmentDefinitionPropertyName) {
        this.environmentDefinitionPropertyName = environmentDefinitionPropertyName;
    }

    public String getDefaultEnvironment() {
        return defaultEnvironment;
    }

    public void setDefaultEnvironment(String defaultEnvironment) {
        this.defaultEnvironment = defaultEnvironment;
    }

    public String getEnvironmentSystemPropertyName() {
        return environmentSystemPropertyName;
    }

    public void setEnvironmentSystemPropertyName(String environmentSystemPropertyName)
    {
        this.environmentSystemPropertyName = environmentSystemPropertyName;
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory)
        throws BeansException
    {
        String activeEnvironment = System.getProperty(environmentSystemPropertyName);
        log.warn("PostProcessing ApplicationContext for Environment: "+activeEnvironment+" from "+prefix);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(int order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

}
```

When the application starts, Spring loads all the contexts and our custom class is called.
In the `init()` method first loads the `environmentDefinitionPropertyName` through the injected `properties` property and then set is as a system property having as a key the `environmentDefinitionPropertyName` value set in the bean definition.

After that, the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` can load the properties file location since it resolves:

```
<property name="location" value="${application-config.prefix}application-config/${application-config.env}/application.properties" />
```

into

```
<property name="location" value="classpath:application-config/DEV/application.properties" />
```

This approach had these principal advantages:

- you can easily add further environments just adding another folder under the original configuration folder
- the original application package was the same on all environments
- the properties file has a 'normal' `key=value` format, like your application.properties file.

Hope this helps and may help others as well.

Comment: This is great solution for spring base application, unfortunately our application doesn’t use spring. Properties are loaded directly from java.